# How to create a link in message app opening from ADOBE AIR app

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I've got an AIR app that open the sms app installed on the phone of the user like that ;

```
function gotoSms():void{
     if(isAndroid){
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("sms:"+mySavedData.data.phoneNumber_friend+"?body=Je suis en danger. Voici ma position : https://www.google.com/maps?q="+mySavedData.data.Userlatitude+","+mySavedData.data.Userlongitude+"(My+Point)&z=14&ll="+mySavedData.data.Userlatitude+","+mySavedData.data.Userlongitude+""));

     }else{
      FPMessages.phone.reinit();
  FPMessages.phone.setBody('Je suis en danger. Voici ma position : https://www.google.com/maps?q="+mySavedData.data.Userlatitude+","+mySavedData.data.Userlongitude+"(My+Point)&z=14&ll="+mySavedData.data.Userlatitude+","+mySavedData.data.Userlongitude+""');
  //
  var r1:String = mySavedData.data.phoneNumber_friend;
  FPMessages.phone.setRecipients([r1]);
  //
  FPMessages.phone.autoHide = true;
  FPMessages.phone.show();   
     }
```

In the body text, there is a link (google map). But when when receiving the sms, the link is not consider as a link but only text (so you can't click on the link directly...).

Is it possible to make the message app "detects" that there is a link ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `href` in your links...

If the example below for `FPMessages.phone.setBody(etc etc...` works okay for showing a link to `google.com` then that is your solution (just replace with your own Map's link).

```
FPMessages.phone.setBody('Je suis en danger. Voici ma position : testing link : <a href="https://www.google.com"> Google.com</a> ... Merci');
```